# I can't seem to close byobu splits using alt f5

Tags: byobu

I am using byobu with tmux and I am trying to collapse the 4 splits I have on the window, but it is not responsive.

When I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> nothing happens.

How do I collapse the splits in this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the hot key you're looking for is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Hi Dustin, Ctrl - F6 will detached the whole session not just one split screen. I have couple of screens and I usually close them by simply writing "exit" but now it stuck in insert mode so no matter what I can't close it. any idea?